# Required keys for multiple objects

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I've enum for my i18n object like:

```
export enum I18NKeys {
  EN = 'en',
  CS = 'cs',
  DE = 'de'
}
```

And I would like to have an object that has keys of `I18NKeys` and there will be custom keys inside that object like

```
export const content = {
  en: {

  },
  cs: {

  },
  de: {

  }
}
```

I'm trying to create a generic typescript that once I've keyed in one of the `I18NKeys` object. So I would like to be sure that others have the same key.

```
export const content = {
  en: {
   title: "Hello"
  },
  cs: {

  },
  de: {

  }
}
```

So this will throw me an error till I've put `title` on all other keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
export const content: Record<I18NKeys, {title: string}> = { 
...
}
```

And of course, you can change {title: string} to any types you want or even generics to suit your need.

Comment: The problem with this I don't want to provide them 1 by 1 in there. I would like to have typescript recognize the keys from each other and asks it to put.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this, you can use the `?` to describe the optional field.

```js
export enum I18NKeys {
    EN = "en",
    CS = "cs",
    DE = "de"
}

interface I18NContent {
    title?: string;
}

const content: Record<I18NKeys, I18NContent> = {
    en: {
        title: "foo"
    },
    cs: {},
    de: {}
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwJIEYAcA5AaWAE8BnOAbwCgBIAUTzgF44AiJVgGloGEBlZmwDGpLrQAidQawAmwVlQC+VKgEtEMYFABmAQyHBMuPDwgak8ajRiqYAG2AB+AFxxSMKOoDmAbiUqhM3c4QPMNVwAlYECoGQAebHwiMk4jfFMwmAA+QSskVytrWwdXVm0ICAUaRW4aEQKa2jkGpSA)